# Rvest Scraping - Time Class's HTML attribute title has a different value comparing with webpage - 9 hours difference

Tags: r, web-scraping, locale, rvest, setlocale

I am scraping customer reviews from Bestbuy USA webpage using **Rvest**.

I encountered a quite strange case, there is a difference in the review date information between webpage and my scraped data. The difference is 9 hours for each review.

E.g:

`<time class="submission-date" title="Dec 28, 2019 2:42 AM">1 week ago</time>`

```
html_nodes(review_page,".review-context .submission-date") %>% html_attr("title")
```

Result: "Dec 27, 2019 5:42 PM"

As you can see, my code is returning 9 hours before.

My session info:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

I am supposing the reason for the issue is timezone. My proxy is in UK. I tried to change locale information but went away empty-handed.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "USA")

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
```

Comment: You can use the `tz` argument to specify the correct timezone. Also, use `strptime` to get date and time. Not sure how you're getting that output with `as.Date`

Comment: I am sorry, you are right the result is not correct, I have updated the code.